# What are best practices for production database schema updates?

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, production-environment

I'm using migrations for managing db changes in development and applying them to production.
But once I've run the migrations in production I delete them as running `php artisan migrate:refresh` could easily wipe out a lot of useful production data.

I wonder if what I'm doing is something people normally do or if I should manage dev to production workflow differently. What are best practices to this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Laravel 4.2, when you run `php artisan migrate` in production - it will give you a clear warning that you are running on the production server, and prompt you `are you sure?` in the console. That way to can be careful that you only ever run the migrate command correctly.

The other option is using something like Laravel Forge or Laravel Envoy, which have deployment scripts, so it automatically does something like

```
php artisan down
git pull
composer install
php artisan migrate
composer dump
php artisan optimize
php artisan up
```

So that the workflow is always correct.